# Importing Flash Builder 4.5 project into Flash Builder 4.5.1

Tags: flash, apache-flex, import, air, builder

I have an AIR project that I was working on Flash Builder 4.5 which now I'm trying to import to my updated Flash Builder 4.5.1 and it is prompting me to fix some paths before the import is completed. I'm kinda clueless what I should put in those fields. Can someone who've done this help me out please?

[see the image]
http://twitpic.com/5hke29

The project access a web server to retrieve data using JSON.

Comment: Are you using Flash Builder PHP Edition?  Did you have other project types associated w/ the project?  It doesn't look like those paths have anything to do w/ Flex.

Comment: Are you using Flash Builder PHP Edition? Nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't that complicated to solve this and it has nothing to do with any PHP features. I simply had a web service running with this project and since I have not exported my project settings properly when imported some variables were unidentified by Flash Builder. If anyone else run into this problem the variables are,

Output folder location - the path on my localhost where the generated files should be put by Flash Builder

Web root - http://localhost (mostly)

Root URL - the URL to my web service.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to set some environment variables on your computer in which the workstation is being used...I haven't utilized the PHP features, but it appears to me that you need to install flash builder PHP edition in order to have these path variables setup for you